# Django Serialize a JsonField, Django Rest API

Tags: json, django, rest, django-models, serialization

I have a class for example

```
from django.forms import JSONField

class Area(models.model):
  GeoJson = JSONField
  ...
```

and a serializer for the class

```
class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  model = Areas
  fields = ('GeoJson',
              ...    )
```

but when I try to get the data from my rest frame work I get this error

```
Object of type 'JSONField' is not JSON serializable
```

What am I doing wrong? it is my first time using django and I need to store GeoJson in the database so im really stuck on how to fix this issue as I dont understand why it wont work, Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a form field in your model, not Django's [**`JSONField`** *model* field <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField). It should be:

```
#         models 🖟
from django.db.models import JSONField

class Area(models.model):
    geojson = JSONField()
```

You however might be interested to work with a [*spatial field type* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#spatial-field-types), and take a look at [**`django-geojson`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson) for GeoJSON functionality.

Comment: For some reason my code cant resolve the django.models import

Comment: @JackDuffy: I made a typo: it is `django.db.models`.

Comment: Ahhh I see, when I ran it now it seemed to work but now I got the message (fields.E180) SQLite does not support JSONFields which doesnt fill me with hope

Comment: @JackDuffy: you need to enable the JSON1 extension https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#sqlite-json1

Comment: I believe I added it right I now get this error even after making a new migration with null and blank set to true. CHECK constraint failed: (JSON_VALID("GeoJson") OR "GeoJson" IS NULL)

Comment: @JackDuffy: it means your `GeoJson` field contains data that is not null or valid JSON.

Comment: I ended up just deleting the migrations folder and remade the migrations from scratch and I believe it has worked lol. entered "GeoJson": "{Test}", in postman and it didnt throw an error back at me for once so I think thats it working, may still be storing that as a string though with the ""

Comment: @JackDuffy: yes, it is storing this as a string, since you passed a string value, you can for example pass an object like `"GeoJson": {"Foo": "Bar"}`.

Comment: Tried that and got "GeoJson": {
            "Foo": "Bar"
        }, as the output so believe that works